# Is it possible to create desktop apps using Spring framework?

Tags: spring, hibernate, jsf, primefaces, desktop-application

I'm about to develop a desktop app. I want to work with java programming using Spring framework and Hibernate. 
I have two questions:
1- Is it possible to create a portable desktop app using Spring framework?
2- What are the components I need to create a desktop app with a nice GUI? (Like primeFaces, JSF or others)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The answer to your question effectively is 'yes' but would you want to...

Comment: @Kukeltje thank you for your quick answer. I would like to use the best and the actual technologies. any recommendations are appreciated..

Comment: Stackoverflow is not for 'reccomendations' since they tend to be subjective. Most likely it will be marked as 'off-topic then. See [ask]